# Deleting a named pipe before processes ends?

Tags: linux, named-pipes

Can I take it for granted that a named-pipe continues to work until the related proceses ends even though it's deleted. Cause it's happening:

```
o@dekstop:~$ mkfifo pipe
o@dekstop:~$ cat < pipe &
[1] 22467
o@dekstop:~$ cat > pipe
echo1         
echo1
echo2
echo2
^Z
[2]+  Stopped                 cat > pipe
o@dekstop:~$ rm pipe
o@dekstop:~$ fg
cat > pipe
echo3
echo3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes; Linux won't truly remove a named pipe as long as some process is still has it open, just like it won't remove regular files.